# Input area displaying different in IE vs Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have created a login area for my website using a table and standard CSS. My problem is IE is adding something in there which is making it render different to firefox and chrome.

I'm wanting the input[type=text"] to be a fixed width and display in the table as it does in chrome.

[image: The top image is IE, bottom is Chrome]

The top image is IE, the bottom is Chrome. IE is not setting the fixed width and is adding some sort of padding in there.

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big,
cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img,
ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
center, u, b, i, marquee {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;/*border: 0px;*/outline: 0px;}
body  {background: #F4F4F3 url(../images/bg.gif) repeat 0 0;font-size: .80em;font-family: ‘Lucida Grande’, ‘Lucida Sans’, ‘Lucida Sans Unicode’, Arial, sans-serif;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;color: #2B2818;}
#ctl00_login td {max-height:28px;padding:0px;}
#ctl00_login input[type="text"] {padding:0px; margin:0px;width:155px;}
```

.aspx file

```
                    <div id="login" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <table style="margin: 0 auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="middle" width="64px">
                                Username:
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="logUser" runat="server" CssClass="login-input"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="logUserRqd" ControlToValidate="logUser" runat="server"
                                    Text="&nbsp;<img src='images/err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your username'>"
                                    ErrorMessage="Please enter your username"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="middle" width="64px">
                                Password:
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">
                                <asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" ID="logPwd" runat="server" CssClass="login-input"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="logPwdRqd" ControlToValidate="logPwd" runat="server"
                                    Text="&nbsp;<img src='images/err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your password'>"
                                    ErrorMessage="Please enter your password"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="~/Account/Register.aspx">Register</a>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Button ID="loginBtn" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="loginBtn_Click" class="button" Style="margin: 3px 25px 0 0;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

**EDIT**
I discovered the fixed width for the second one was because it was type="password" not text, so that is fixed. It's just the padding that is the issue now.

**Update**
So not sure what happened. Didn't change any CSS or anything, but added JQuery 1.7.1 into my page and then did a ctrl+F5 on the page and it was suddenly fixed.

Comment: i suggest meyer reset, the most drastical and violent css reset.

Comment: IE screwing up? Why am I not surprised?

Comment: @tree that didn't do anything. :(

Comment: If you don't specify the width of a td or table, browsers will do their best to make it look ok and fit the contents. Why not give the td a width in the css?

Comment: Try to get over using tables for layout, your quality of life will greatly improve when you master a bit of semantic html and good css. I'd avoid using dynamic .net IDs as your css selectors as it is possible for them to change if you restructure anything which will break your css. Add a CssClass instead and use that as a selector.

Comment: @DanPorter I only use tables for login box's etc, not my general layout. It's much cleaner and easier to code for cross browser compatibility. But thanks for the ID suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE are you using?  Some versions of IE are known to display HTML incorrectly, in particular padding/margins and alignment.  In fact, issues with IE (particularly older versions) are so frustrating & time consuming that one Australian eCommerce firm is charging users of IE7 extra to cover the extra costs associated with supporting it!

As already mentioned, a CSS reset is one way of dealing with this problem.

Another way to address the issue is to conditionally include an IE-specific style sheet in your template.  eg.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link href="older.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

This example will apply the stylesheet 'older.css' to any version of IE older than 8 (eg. IE7, IE6), but not IE8 itself.  You can use lte/gte to target versions less than/greater than that specified, or you can omit them entirely to target a specific version.  You can also target other browsers if you wish.

This isn't a complete answer to your question, but should point you in the right direction.  I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. Helps a little, however the problem is even using developer tools I can't find any padding or margins or anything. I'm using IE9. :)

Comment: Try having a look at the field labels, and also on the table itself (cellpadding/cellspacing/etc)